# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use ajax in class based Listview for pagination.

```
#views.py
class HomePage(ListView):
   model = Video
   template_name = 'index.html'


   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      videos = Video.objects.filter(category='sub')
      paginator = Paginator(videos, 5)
      page = self.request.GET.get('page2')
      try:
          videos = paginator.page(page)
      except PageNotAnInteger:
          videos = paginator.page(1)
      except EmptyPage:
          videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

   context['videos'] = videos

   if self.request.is_ajax():
       html = render_to_string('video/index2.html', context,   request=self.request)
       return JsonResponse({'form' : html })
        
   else:
       return context
```

The error I getting using this views is:-

```
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.
```

If you have any different ways to achieve this ajax pagination .Please mention that.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you try like this `return JsonResponse(html)`  instead of `return JsonResponse({'form' : html })`  ??

Comment: I tried that but got another error.TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.

Comment: please print html variable like this `print(html)`  for check having data.

Comment: It's printing nothing to console

Comment: `Video` table no data ??

Comment: No, Sorry, I made some mistake its printing next videos li tags data

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eL2RGXl getting next page div elements with print(html) in console.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this `return JsonResponse(html, safe=False)` instead of `return JsonResponse({'form' : html })`

Comment: Nope, still error TypeError: context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.